# How to proof $P(AB) \le P(A)P(B)$?

Tags: probability

How to proof for all A and B, $P(AB) \le P(A)P(B)$?

I only know that if A and B are independent, then $P(AB) = P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Why do you think it is true?

Comment: What is true is $P(AB)\le P(A)$ and $P(AB)\le P(B)$, so that $[P(AB)]^2\le P(A)P(B)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because it is wrong.
The probability of rolling an odd number $\in\{1,3,5\}$ with a fair  die is $P(A)=\frac12$. The probability of rolling a prime number $\in\{2,3,5\}$ is $P(B)=\frac12$. The probability of rolling an odd prime $\in\{3,5\}$ is $P(AB)=\frac13>\frac14$.